# Format Twitter API Endpoint in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-apps-script, twitter

I am trying to create a a google apps script to post data (a direct message) to a recipient using google sheets.

The [[Twitter API documenation]](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event) indicates that information can be posted like this:

```
curl --request POST 
--url https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json 
--header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_nonce="AUTO_GENERATED_NONCE", oauth_signature="AUTO_GENERATED_SIGNATURE", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="AUTO_GENERATED_TIMESTAMP", oauth_token="USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0"' 
--header 'content-type: application/json' 
--data '{"event": {"type": "message_create", "message_create": {"target": {"recipient_id": "RECIPIENT_USER_ID"}, "message_data": {"text": "Hello World!"}}}}'
twurl -A 'Content-type: application/json' -X POST /1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json -d '{"event": {"type": "message_create", "message_create": {"target": {"recipient_id": "RECIPIENT_USER_ID"}, "message_data": {"text": "Hello World!"}}}}'
```

The thing is i am new to this. How do I represent this in Javascript? I have this so far:

```
var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json";
var headers = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers":{"authorization": OAuth oauth_consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY", 
               oauth_nonce="AUTO_GENERATED_NONCE", 
               oauth_signature="AUTO_GENERATED_SIGNATURE", 
               oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
               oauth_timestamp="AUTO_GENERATED_TIMESTAMP", 
               oauth_token="USERS_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
               oauth_version="1.0"
    },
    "data": {"event": {"type": "message_create", "message_create": {"target": {"recipient_id": "RECIPIENT_USER_ID"}, "message_data": {"text": "Hello World!"}}}}
    };

    var response = twitterService.fetch(url, headers);

    if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
        status = "SENT";
    } else {            
        status = "ERROR: " + JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).errors[0].message;
    }
```

How do I format this in the right way?

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? You want to convert the above curl command to Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? And also, have you already had the correct values of `oauth_nonce`, `oauth_signature` and `oauth_token`?

Comment: Yes, I want to implement it in Google Apps Script. I actually do not have the correct values of oauth_nonce, oauth_signature and oauth_token. They are all strange to me

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation. Do you have the values which are required to test the script? For example, when you run the curl command using your values which are required to authorize, could you confirm that the response you expected could be got?

Comment: The response is “reference error: empty Json string”. I am sure my Json format is wrong, I need help to write it correctly

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your current stage, the above curl command cannot be used. If my understanding is correct, when the curl command is converted to Google Apps Script, how will you test the script?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “how will I test the script?” And if the curl command cannot be used, what then can be used

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I thought that in your situation, after the curl command was converted to Google Apps Script, you cannot test the converted script because you have no invalid values for authorizing. In your case, how will you check whether the script works? If my understanding for your situation is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: I currently don’t have oauth values, but I can always figure out how to request that after solving this problem. My current problem is that I do not know how to write the Twitter API code in JavaScript. I don’t know how to format it perfectly for google apps script, I am asking how do I arrange/type the JSON data

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your goal is to convert the curl command to 2 scripts of both Javascript and Google Apps Script. But you are not required to test the converted scripts. Is my understanding correct? And `JSON data` of `how do I arrange/type the JSON data` is `--data '{"event": {"type": "message_create", "message_create": {"target": {"recipient_id": "RECIPIENT_USER_ID"}, "message_data": {"text": "Hello World!"}}}}'`?

Comment: So it is not possible to send a direct message on twitter using google apps script?

Comment: I think that it can be achieved with Google Apps Script.

Comment: So, what do I do? I’m at the stage of sending out a post request

Comment: Thank you for replying. How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040955/format-twitter-api-endpoint-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment104325655_59040955)?

Comment: How do I send that?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that I cannot support about your question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: I've figured it out. All i was asking for is the format to code it in

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
        "event": {
          "type": "message_create",
          "message_create": {
            "target": {
              "recipient_id": "2913462268"
            },
            "message_data": {
              "text": "Hello World!",
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // request options
      var options = {
        'method' : 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'escaping': false,
        // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
      };
```